# Arrows used in chemical reactions

Tags: notation

A point was raised about arrows used in a chemical reaction. I think we can all agree that $\ce{->}$ arrow in the reaction

$$\ce{A + B -> C} \tag{1}$$

means that the reaction goes in one direction. But what of

$$\ce{A + B <-> C} \tag{2}$$

$$\ce{A + B <=> C} \tag{3}$$

$$\ce{A + B <--> C} \tag{4}$$

$$\ce{A + B <=>> C} \tag{5}$$

$$\ce{A + B <<=> C} \tag{6}$$

Is there any IUPAC or American Chemical Society guideline about how double arrows are supposed to be used?

---

#### Examples of usage:

> (1) Used for example:
>   "Removal of Triphenylphosphine Oxide by Precipitation with Zinc Chloride in Polar Solvents",
>   Donald C. Batesky, Matthew J. Goldfogel, and Daniel J. Weix,
>   [J. Org. Chem., 2017, 82 (19), pp 9931–9936](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.joc.7b00459?src=recsys)
>
> "Cation Radical Accelerated Nucleophilic Aromatic Substitution via Organic Photoredox Catalysis",
>   Nicholas E. S. Tay and David A. Nicewicz*
>   Department of Chemistry, University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, Chapel Hill, North Carolina 27599-3290, United States
>   [J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2017, 139 (45), pp 16100–16104](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.7b10076)
>
> (4) Used for example:
>   "Cation Radical Accelerated Nucleophilic Aromatic Substitution via Organic Photoredox Catalysis",
>   Nicholas E. S. Tay and David A. Nicewicz*
>   Department of Chemistry, University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, Chapel Hill, North Carolina 27599-3290, United States
>   [J. Am. Chem. Soc., 2017, 139 (45), pp 16100–16104](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jacs.7b10076)

---

**Previous questions in *Chemistry*:**

In his answer user Chemgoat noted that this question had been asked before:

[What are the correct equilibrium arrows?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43212/what-are-the-correct-equilibrium-arrows)

A comment on that question points to yet another

[What is the difference between "reaction in both directions" and "equilibrium"?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20127/what-is-the-difference-between-reaction-in-both-directions-and-equilibrium)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The [IUPAC Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf) (Quantities,
Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry, Third Edition, 2007) reads:**

> **2.10.1 Other symbols and conventions in chemistry**
>   [...]
>   **[(iv) Equations for chemical reactions](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf#page=67)**
>
> (a) On a *microscopic* level the reaction equation represents an
>   elementary reaction [...] A single arrow is used to connect reactants
>   and products in an elementary reaction. An equal sign is used for the
>   "net" reaction, the result of a set of elementary reactions. [...]
>
> $\ce{H + Br2 -> HBr + Br} \quad$ one elementary step in HBr formation
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 = 2 HBr} \quad$ the sum of several such elementary steps
>
> (b) On a *macroscopic* level, different
>   symbols are used connecting the reactants and products in the reaction
>   equation, with the following meanings:
>
> $\ce{H2 + Br2 = 2 HBr}\quad$ stoichiometric equation
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 -> 2 HBr}\quad$ net forward reaction
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 <--> 2 HBr}\quad$ reaction, both directions
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 <=> 2 HBr}\quad$ equilibrium
>
> The two-sided arrow $\ce{<->}$ should not be used
>   for reactions to avoid confusion with resonance structures [...]
>
> **2.12.1 Other symbols, terms, and conventions used in chemical kinetics**
>   [...]
>   [(ii) Composite mechanisms](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf#page=83)
>   A reaction that involves more than one elementary reaction is said to occur by a composite mechanism. The terms complex mechanism, indirect mechanism, and stepwise mechanism are also commonly used. Special types of mechanisms include chain-reaction mechanisms, catalytic reaction mechanisms, etc.
>
> > *Examples* 
> >     A simple mechanism is composed of forward and reverse reactions
> >     $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ce{A -> B + C}$
> >     $\quad\quad\quad\quad\ce{B + C -> A}$
> >     It is in this particular case conventional to write these in one line
> >     $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ce{A <--> B + C}$
>
> However, it is useful in kinetics to distinguish this from a net reaction, which is written either with two one-sided arrows or an "equal" sign
>   $\quad\quad\ce{A <=> B + C}$
>   $\quad\quad\ce{A =  B + C}$
>
> When one combines a composite mechanism to obtain a net reaction, one should not use the simple arrow in the resulting equation. 
>   $\quad$*Example* 
>   $$\begin{align}
> \ce{A &\to B + C}\quad\text{ unimolecular elementary reaction} \\
> \ce{B + C &\to D +E}\quad\text{ bimolecular elementary reaction} \\
> \hline
> \ce{A &= D + E}\quad\text{net reaction (no elementary reaction,no molecularity)} 
> \end{align}$$

---

**[The ACS Style Guide](http://aerosol.chem.uci.edu/intranet/writing/ACS_style_guide.pdf#page=321) reads:**

> Many kinds and combinations of arrows can be used. For example, two
>   full arrows in opposite directions ($\ce{<-->}$) indicate a reaction that is
>   proceeding in both  directions. Two arrows with half heads in opposite
>   directions ($\ce{<=>}$) indicate a  reaction in equilibrium. A single arrow
>   with heads on both sides ($\ce{<->}$) indicates  resonance structures, not a
>   reaction.

Comment: PS. I realize that the arrow display degraded a little bit. I will improve that with the next release of MathJax/mhchem.

Answer (score 20):

The second one, $(2)$, $\ce{<->}$, indicates resonance structures.

The difference between the second two is explained in another post -

[What are the correct equilibrium arrows?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43212/what-are-the-correct-equilibrium-arrows)

Loong basically says that $\ce{<-->}$, $(4)$, indicates forward and reverse elementary steps happening in equilibrium, that is that those are the only two things actually reacting with each other. On the other hand, $\ce{<=>}$, $(3)$, indicates a net reaction, that is that there may be multiple steps in between, leading to this net equation. He does a more in depth explanation of this in his post.

Case $(5)$ indicates a net equilibrium where products are favored, and $(6)$ indicates a net equilibrium where reactants are favored.