# What does an equal sign mean in chemical equations?

Tags: notation

I have been doing a bit of literature review, and have come across a few equations which use an equal sign (=) instead of an arrow, for example:

$$\ce{Fe^2+ + 1/2O2 = 2Fe^3+ + H2O}$$

What does the equal sign mean? Is the same as a single arrow $\ce{->}$ or the double arrow $\ce{<=>}$?

Comment: the gist is that it means a net or overall reaction.

Answer (score 3):

**The [IUPAC Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf) (Quantities,
Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry, Third Edition, 2007) reads:**

> **2.10.1 Other symbols and conventions in chemistry**
>   [...]
>   **[(iv) Equations for chemical reactions](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf#page=67)**
>
> (a) On a *microscopic* level the reaction equation represents an
>   elementary reaction [...] A single arrow is used to connect reactants
>   and products in an elementary reaction. An **equal sign** is used for the
>   **"net" reaction**, the result of a set of elementary reactions. [...]
>
> $\ce{H + Br2 -> HBr + Br} \quad$ one elementary step in HBr formation
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 = 2 HBr} \quad$ the sum of several such elementary steps
>
> (b) On a *macroscopic* level, different
>   symbols are used connecting the reactants and products in the reaction
>   equation, with the following meanings:
>
> $\ce{H2 + Br2 = 2 HBr}\quad$ stoichiometric equation
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 -> 2 HBr}\quad$ net forward reaction
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 <--> 2 HBr}\quad$ reaction, both directions
>   $\ce{H2 + Br2 <=> 2 HBr}\quad$ equilibrium
>
> The two-sided arrow $\ce{<->}$ should not be used
>   for reactions to avoid confusion with resonance structures [...]
>
> **2.12.1 Other symbols, terms, and conventions used in chemical kinetics**
>   [...]
>   [(ii) Composite mechanisms](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf#page=83)
>   A reaction that involves more than one elementary reaction is said to occur by a composite mechanism. The terms complex mechanism, indirect mechanism, and stepwise mechanism are also commonly used. Special types of mechanisms include chain-reaction mechanisms, catalytic reaction mechanisms, etc.
>
> > *Examples* 
> >     A simple mechanism is composed of forward and reverse reactions
> >     $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ce{A -> B + C}$
> >     $\quad\quad\quad\quad\ce{B + C -> A}$
> >     It is in this particular case conventional to write these in one line
> >     $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ce{A <--> B + C}$
>
> However, it is useful in kinetics to distinguish this from **a net reaction**, which is written either with two one-sided arrows or an **"equal" sign**
>   $\quad\quad\ce{A <=> B + C}$
>   $\quad\quad\ce{A =  B + C}$
>
> When one combines a composite mechanism to obtain a net reaction, one should not use the simple arrow in the resulting equation. 
>   $\quad$*Example* 
>   $$\begin{align}
> \ce{A &\to B + C}\quad\text{ unimolecular elementary reaction} \\
> \ce{B + C &\to D +E}\quad\text{ bimolecular elementary reaction} \\
> \hline
> \ce{A &= D + E}\quad\text{net reaction (no elementary reaction,no molecularity)} 
> \end{align}$$

Comment: [Déjà Vu](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/86916/41328)

Comment: I'd say, the core fundamentals warrant a repetition if that makes them easier to find for future questioners.

Comment: I just like when it's [dry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), that's all:)

Comment: Rest assured. We covered arrows and we covered equals. I think there cannot be any more questions that could be answered by this quote. :-)

Comment: Right, this sounds fair, +1:)